# Ubuntu not hibernating after running out of battery when the lid is closed?

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, hibernate

I used to work with Windows. When I wanted to stop using my laptop I only closed the lid and even if the Laptop runs out of battery, the state of the machine was saved. So, when I plugged to the AC the Laptop, I was able to continue working.

But now I have Ubuntu 14.04 and when I close the lid and the Laptop runs out of battery, the Laptop is completely powered off. Even when I try to turn it on again the power button do not responds (in windows the LED used to tick 3-2 times as a signal of low batt.). So, I have to keep the power button pressed 5 times for completely shutting of the system in order to press the button again turn the PC on.

What can I do?

Can I enable some kind of automatic hibernation when the lid is closed and runs out of battery?